# Android emulator API 1.6, Manage Applications > (see screenshot)

Tags: android, emulation

I've noticed a strange app on my Android Emulator (1.6)

Does anyone know what this is?  I can't un-install it, and "Force Quit" doesn't seem to do anything.
It doesn't appear to take up any memory, but it has all kinds of permissions.

I don't know how to research this, because I don't read that language.

My specific questions are:

Has anyone seen this on their emulator?

Is it some kind of virus or Trojan, etc.?

Only one screen shot(Dont'ask for more, stackoverflow wont let me.):

http://img834.imageshack.us/i/weirdapp.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Google Pinyin Input Method, a way to input Chinese character using Pinyin. 
You can see more options about this at Settings->Locale & Text.

So, no, that's not a virus or trojan.